# k3s Ingress not work in local server but works well on cloud services

Tags: kubernetes, microservices, k3s, traefik-ingress

Installed k3s on a local server to implement microservices, one of these is the authentication service that has several end points such as **login** or **logout**:

```
auth-http             NodePort    10.43.221.215   <none>        3001:31621/TCP
```

If I try to access via postman using ip address and port, the service works well. I created a ingress file like this:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: lastminute
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /auth/*
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific
            backend:
              service:
                name: auth-http
                port:
                  number: 3001
```

I need that if I use ***http:///auth/login*** or ***http:///auth/logout*** it redirects me to the end points ***login***, ***logout*** or whatever I need.

I can't understand why the ingress file works in services like AWS or Google Cloud but not on my server.

I would appreciate any help you can give me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create [ingress Class Trafeik](https://docs.k3s.io/networking#traefik-ingress-controller) based on the documentation.

Probably it work easily on AWS or GCP since ingress classes are auto propagated on platform managed clusters.

Consider also using [pathType: Prefix](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#path-types) on your deployment.